# Is it true that $ \cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{F}_{\frac{1}{k}}=\cap_{\epsilon >0} \mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Is it true that $ \cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{F}_{\frac{1}{k}}=\cap_{\epsilon >0} \mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}$ where $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}_+}$ is a flitration(increasing family of sub-sigma algebras)
My guess is yes. It is clear that $ \cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{F}_{\frac{1}{k}} \supset\cap_{\epsilon >0} \mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}$ but I am having some troubles showing that the other set inclusion. My idea was that since $\mathcal{F}_t$ is increasing in $t$ , we have that for  $s <t, \mathcal{F}_s \subset \mathcal{F}_t$ and it is clear that

If $A \in \cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{F}_{\frac{1}{k}} \implies \forall k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ , }A \in \mathcal{F}_{\frac{1}{k}}   $ and hence we can also conclude!(I think the reasoning is a bit flawed here) that $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\epsilon} \text{ , } \forall  \epsilon >0$ since for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathcal{F}_{\frac{1}{k}} \subset \mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}$

Does it make sense. Or am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: Your reasoning is fine.